# how to stop master ajax request if slave ajax request fails in extjs

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, extjs

I am newbie to extjs 4.1, I developed a small app wherein I have a master and slave concept i.e basis on master's ajax success i have to fire slave's ajax request, if slave fails then master should also fail and vice versa. Please find the below snipnet of my code

Controller.js

```
    Ext.define('Basel3.controller.Contacts', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        stores:['...My all store goes here...'],
        models:['...My all models goes here...'],
        views: ['...My all views goes here...'],
        refs:[{
            My all references goes here
        }],
        init: function(){
              this.control({
                ....
        })
        },
        save: function() {
              this.getRulesStore().save();
              this.getRuleDetailsStore().save();
        }
    }
```

As in the aforementioned code we can see that I have used the stores to save the data in my database, which fires seperate ajax request, which I don't want to do. Below are the store and model of the respective entities.

Models

Rule Detail:

```
      Ext.define('Basel3.model.RuleDetail', {
         extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
         fields: [{name: 'ruleDetailId', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'ruleId',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'attrName',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'attrType',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'attrOprtr',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'attrValue',type: 'string'}
        ]
      });
```

Rule:

```
    Ext.define('Basel3.model.Rule', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{name: 'ruleName',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'ruleGroup', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'ruleReportName', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'ruleCategory',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'ruleTypeId',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'ruleFactor',type: 'string'},
         {name: 'effDate',type: 'date', dateFormat :'d-M-y'}
        ]
    });
```

Stores:

Rule Details:

```
    Ext.define('Basel3.store.Contacts', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
      model: 'Basel3.model.Contact',
      autoLoad: true,
      pageSize: 35,
      storeId : 'Contacts',
      autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 35},
      sorters: ['attrType'],
      groupField: 'attrType',            
      proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',                
      api: {
        read : 'ruledetail/view.action',
        create : 'ruledetail/create.action',
        update: 'ruledetail/update.action',
        destroy: ''
      },
      model : 'Basel3.model.Contact',

      reader: {                 //reads the data in the JSON Format
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success'
      },

      writer: {
        type: 'json',           //writes the data in the JSON Format
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: true,
        root: 'data'
      },

      listeners: {              //Exception Handler for the Ajax Request
        exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
            var error = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: 'RULE DETAILS REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                msg: error.message,
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        }
    }
}
    });
```

Rules:

```
    Ext.define('IntellectB3.store.Rule', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'IntellectB3.model.Rule',
        storeId : 'Rule',
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: 35,
        autoSync : true,
        autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 35},
        proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',                
        api: {
           read : 'rule/view.action',
           create : 'rule/create.action',
           update: 'rule/update.action',
           destroy: ''
        },

       reader: {                    
           type: 'json',
           root: 'data',
           successProperty: 'success'
       },

      writer: {
         type: 'json',          //writes the data in the JSON Format
         writeAllFields: true,
         encode: true,
         root: 'data'
      },

      listeners: {              //Exception Handler for the Ajax Request
        exception: function(proxy, response, operation){

            var error = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: 'RULE MASTER REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                msg: error.message,
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK

            });
        }
    }
}
    });
```

Thanks in advance, waiting for humble replies

Comment: "...on master's ajax success i have to fire slave's ajax request, if slave fails then master should also fail and vice versa"... how do you plan on this working? If you are truly firing the "slave" request on the AJAX response of the master (which you aren't...), then the "master" request will already be complete and not cancellable in the event of an error in the slave request.

Comment: You should start with clearly defining the workflow you need to accomplish, and then plot that in a way that is in keeping with the way that AJAX requests work.

Comment: Start with the docs for save(): http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save and read about how to implement a callback that can handle the success of your request.